# combine imageview and background image into one string

Tags: swift, dictionary, object, var, combine

I am looking for a way to write swift code faster. SO I am wondering if there is i can combine

```
    grassColor.backgroundColor
```

Into into something like

```
   let combine = grassColor.backgroundColor
```

So I could code this instead of have to type grassColor.backgroundColor = .red every time.

```
@objc func fanColorRed(){
    combine = .red

}

@objc func fanColorBlue(){
    combine = .blue
 }
@objc func fanColorYellow(){
    combine = .yellow

 }
@objc func fanColorOrange(){
    combine = .orange

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Swift's [computed properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259).

```
var combine: NSColor {
  get {
    return grassColor.backgroundColor
  }
  set {
    grassColor.backgroundColor = newValue
  }
}
```

Comment: If you’re targeting iOS, just switch NSColor to UIColor, or whatever type you’re trying to encapsulate in that property.